# Is it possible to have a container that keeps its aspect ratio while resizing according to the screen/window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I've made an example on paint
[image: example painting]

This might be overthinking this but I'm trying to have a div that always keeps its aspect ratio (9:16) and that is showing entirely on screen whatever the windows size. I tried searching for "div keep aspect ratio" but in these cases the div doesn't resize with the window. I thought using javascript to check when the height of the window is greater than its width (and vice versa) and change the css but I don't know if it's possible to run a javascript function upon resizing the page. Also, all my content is in this container and I just want black bars to fill the rest.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do that.

1. use javascript resize function:

```
window.onresize = function() {
       // resize your div according to window size
    };
```

2. use Jquery resize function:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // resize your div according to window size
});
```

3. use css @media   https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
 @media all and (min-height:640px) and (max-height:960px){
    // resize your div according to window size
}
```